# Evaluate condition from a php array

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have an array which is a combination of `true` and `false` with `AND`, `OR` connectors, for example:

```
$array = array(
    "condition_1" => true,
    "connector" => "AND",
    "condition_2" => false
);
```

I want to evaluate it inside an `if` conditional, something like:

```
if(implode(" ", $array)){
    echo "yes";
}else{
    echo "No";
}
```

Is this possible in php?

Comment: But DONT USE EVAL() unless you have to. ___There be Dragons___

Comment: How can I do this? eval("\$conditio = \"implode(" ", $array)\";"); if(conditio){ echo "yes"; }else{ echo "No"; } ?? don'tt work??

Comment: It work!!! $condition = "return " .implode(' ', $array) . ";"; then if(eval($condition)){ echo "yes"; }else{ echo "No"; } thanks a lot!